# WCF Client to use pipe if available or tcp in other cases

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, windows-services

I'm creating very simple application (client) that will connect to simple wcf service.

I would like for client to use pipes if run on the same machine or tcp if run from other machine.

I have endpoints in config configured.

**What is the easiest way to check if client is running on the same machine as service and pipes are available?**

I know I can try to connect to pipe and catch exception if it is not available. But that looks "dirty" in my eyes. As it is not exceptional behavior but something I should check before connecting.

Comment: Something like `if (config.URL.Contains(Dns.GetHostName))`? That still won't mean the service is listening on a pipe though, so I'd still go with trying first.

Comment: I know that I can add option to application cofig to use tcp or pipes. But I don't want user to make that choise because applicaiton should always use pipes for "internal" communiactaion if possible.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I mean you can compare the hostname in the configured named pipes endpoint to the name of the host that the client is running on. If they match, you're quite likely to be on the same machine.